# What was Meteor's contribution to Documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation, advertising

The following advertisement, as shown on the Stack Overflow site, says

> Documentation is now live
>
> Thanks to our launch partner Meteor

[image: SO advertisement saying that Documentation is now live Thanks to Meteor]

What was Meteor's contribution? Purely financial or were Meteor's products used to implement Stack Overflow Documentation?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/07/introducing-stack-overflow-documentation-beta/?cb=1 has some info on this, looks like they've just volunteered curators/helpers for topics pertaining to their technologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the question! Meteor, along with our other launch partners Microsoft, Twilio, PubNub, PayPal, Twitch, Dropbox, and Xamarin, have been working with us through most of the beta to give us much needed feedback. They've been sharing with us a unique insight into what their own developer communities want to see in documentation, and they've been kicking the tires of the product for a few months.

They're also supporting the community today (and beyond) by monitoring their tags in Documentation to see what the community might need that we haven't already thought of.